# Vue router single page app, should the page reload?

Tags: nginx, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a question I have vue router set up which works, however I have a question about how is it a single page app. When I click on the link, page is reloading therefore it is not really a single page app is it?

Here's my nginx configuration:

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/webuilder.co.uk/before/*;

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name webuilder.co.uk;
    root /home/forge/webuilder.co.uk/current;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/webuilder.co.uk/279163/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/webuilder.co.uk/279163/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-$
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/webuilder.co.uk/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
```

Routes:

```
import Create from '../vue/components/homepage/create.vue';
import How from '../vue/components/homepage/how.vue';
import About from '../vue/components/homepage/about.vue';
import Youtube from '../vue/components/homepage/youtube.vue';
import Login from '../vue/components/auth/login.vue';
import Register from '../vue/components/auth/register.vue';

export default [
    { path: '/', component: Create },
    { path: '/how', component: How },
    { path: '/about', component: About},
    { name: 'youtube', path: '/youtube', component: Youtube},
    { path: '/login', component: Login},
    { path: '/register', component: Register},
];

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.component('homenav', Navigation);
Vue.component('mainav', Navigation2);

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: Router
});

new Vue({
  el: '#nav',
  data: {
    nav: 'homeNav'
  },
  methods: {
    switchNav: function (nav) {
      this.nav = nav;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  updated: function () {
    Pace.restart()
  },
});
```

and it can be seen at:

https://webuilder.co.uk

Can someone just explain and clarify if that is a expected behaviour of SPA? I thought it will not reload but change the component itself which it does if i turn history mode off and add '#'...

Comment: You are correct, it should't reload. have you seen this (the server config part): https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`<router-link>`](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html) instead of `<a>` when you want to route to a particular router page:

> In HTML5 history mode, router-link will intercept the click event so that the browser doesn't try to reload the page.

Comment: Makes sense I have used my own a tag and thought it will be the same. So I will need to change that. Thanks